# Flex rerender datagrid headers

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid, header, renderer

This is my code:

```
public function set dataProvider(value:Object):void
{
...

dg.columns = new ArrayList();
var col:DataGridColumn = new DataGridColumn();
col.headerRenderer = new ClassFactory(CustomHeaderRenderer);
dg.columns.Add(col);
...
```

same routine for secondDG

```
...
dg.dataProvider = value;
secondDG.dataProvider = value;
}
```

....

```
<s:HGroup>
  <s:DataGrid id="dg"/>
  <s:DataGrid id="SecondDG"/>
</s:HGroup>
```

....

```
<renderer>
  override protected function updateDisplayList(.):void
{
rendering happens there from super.owner variables
}

</renderer>
```

dg has 7 columns, secondDG - 1. All 8 columns use same `headerRenderer`. The problem is: renderer doesn't notice, when variables in owner component changes. I need some way to force all headers to rerender (`dg.dataProvider.refresh;` rerenders only cells).

Comment: dispatch a custom event when variables changes in owner component .. and listen to him on renderer

Comment: doesn't it work the other way around? Like parent listens to events from children